# php pdo oop fetch data not working

Tags: php, oop, pdo

Class PHP

```
<?php

    class product extends db {

        function viewCat(){

            $dbcon = new db();
            $connn = $dbcon->dbcon();

            try {
                $stmt = $connn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `cat`");

                $resultcat = $stmt->execute();

                return $resultcat;

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }

        }  

    }

    ?>
```

the view

```
<?php
$menu = new product();

$resultmenux = $menu->viewCat();


    foreach ($resultcatx as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }

?>
```

the error i get is

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: you are just executing query.. `you are not fetching data`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your class file it should be, as I commented you are not fetching the data

```
$stmt = $connn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `cat`");

$stmt->execute();

$resultcat = $stml->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // this line was missing

return $resultcat;
```

and in view file as answered by shankhan

```
$resultmenux = $menu->viewCat();    

foreach ($resultmenux as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
$resultmenux = $menu->viewCat();


foreach ($resultmenux as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```